# Displaying JSON properties of same object on different HTML pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following js script and json that I am appending to an HTML table.

Depending on which "MD_PERCENT" (MD column) is clicked within the table, I want it to link to another html document (indexmd.html) and display a few more properties (DISCHARGE_NOTE, DN_NOTE_STATUS, HP_NOTE, HP_NOTE_STATUS) of the object that the clicked MD_PERCENT is associated to within another HTML table.

I have the MD_PERCENT column of the table as an anchor....but how can I make the "new table" display the appropriate/related data when clicked?

Hopefully my noob question makes sense...

Main html table:

```
<table class="footable">
        <thead>
                <th width="150">Patient Name</th>
                <th width="75">FIN</th>
                <th width="50">Nurse Unit</th>
                <th width="50">Room</th>
                <th width="50">Bed</th>                 
                <th width="150">Attending Physician</th>
                <th width="100">Length of Stay</th>
                <th width="100">Medical Assessment</th>
                <th width="50">RT</th>
                <th width="50">SW</th>
                <th width="50">MD</th>
                <th width="50">RN</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

json:

```
{
"COPD_QUAL": 15,
"LIST": [
    {
        "PATIENT": "TEST,    TRICKLE",
        "FIN": "70100905",
        "NURSE_UNIT": "TIC",
        "ROOM": "C219",
        "BED": "A",
        "ATTENDING_PHYS": "LEVITEN , DANIEL L",
        "LENGTH_OF_STAY": "171days 02:14:15",
        "MED_ASSESS": "Mild exacerbation",
        "RT_PERCENT":0,
        "SW_PERCENT":0,
        "MD_PERCENT":20,
        "RN_PERCENT":0,
        "DISCHARGE_NOTE": "General Procedure",
        "DN_NOTE_STATUS": "Auth (Verified)",
        "HP_NOTE": "Admission H&P",
        "HP_NOTE_STATUS": "Auth (Verified)",
        "ACTIVITY_ID": 305675472.0000,
        "PERSON_ID": 8986122,
        "ENCNTR_ID": 14150574
    },
    {
        "PATIENT":"TEST, GRAYSON2",
        "FIN":"65002059",
        "NURSE_UNIT":"B7A",
        "ROOM":"B701",
        "BED":"B",
        "ATTENDING_PHYS":"Test , Physician",
        "LENGTH_OF_STAY":"155days 00:43:16",
        "MED_ASSESS":"",
        "RT_PERCENT":0,
        "SW_PERCENT":0,
        "MD_PERCENT":60,
        "RN_PERCENT":0,
        "DISCHARGE_NOTE": "Angina",
        "DN_NOTE_STATUS": "Modified",
        "HP_NOTE": "Fever",
        "HP_NOTE_STATUS": "Auth (Verified)",
        "ACTIVITY_ID":0.0,
        "PERSON_ID":9100122,
        "ENCNTR_ID":14278577
    }
]
}
```

js function to append data to main html table:

```
 function createPatientTable(json) {
$.each(json.LIST, function(i, COPD_QUAL) {
    $('.footable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + COPD_QUAL.PATIENT + '</td><td><a href="javascript:APPLINK(0,\'powerchart.exe\',\'/PERSONID=' + COPD_QUAL.PERSON_ID + ' /ENCNTRID=' + COPD_QUAL.ENCNTR_ID + '\')">' + COPD_QUAL.FIN + '</a></td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.NURSE_UNIT + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.ROOM + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.BED + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.ATTENDING_PHYS + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.LENGTH_OF_STAY + '</td><td id ="medassess" class="assessment ' + getSeverity(COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS) + '" onclick="openPowerform(\'' + COPD_QUAL.PERSON_ID + '\', \'' + COPD_QUAL.ENCNTR_ID + '\', \'' + COPD_QUAL.ACTIVITY_ID + '\')">' + COPD_QUAL.MED_ASSESS + '</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.RT_PERCENT + '\%</td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.SW_PERCENT + '\%</td><td><a href="../indexmd.html">' + COPD_QUAL.MD_PERCENT + '\%</a></td><td>' + COPD_QUAL.RN_PERCENT + '\%</td></tr>');
});
$('.footable').footable();
};
```

md html table that I wish to display additional info:

```
<h3>Patient Name</h3>
<table id="tablemd">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Discharge Note</th>
            <th>Discharge Note Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>General Procedure</td>
            <td>Auth (Verified)</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>H&P Note</th>
            <th>H&P Note Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Admission H&P</td>
            <td>Auth (Verified)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the page, for example from `index_1.html` to `index_2.html` then there is almost no reference. You cannot determine on `index_2.html` what exactly was clicked on the first page.

You have to create some sort of reference by yourself. For example a query string parameter.

You can read something about query strings [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

if you then want to know, was query string is used on index_2.html, you might want to use some javascript code that parses the query string. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

After receiving the necessary parameter, you can then filter your data and fetch only the part you want.